# Regex that allows dashes and numbers only?

Tags: ruby, regex

What is the regex to allow dashes and numbers only?

A good example is use in a phone number. e.g. 555-555-555, 12-2314-425.

I don't want entries like: `-------------` though but `-34--53-343` is fine for now.

Comment: RegEx doesn't have memory, you cannot guarantee a number will be present among dashes if all the spots can be taken up by either one.

Comment: @TheZ Ruby and other dynamic language regexp's certainly "have memory" as [they support backreferences](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#label-Capturing). One doesn't need "memory" to make a regex match this question's desired behavior, see my answer below.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

So in the problem as stated, you want at least one digit but otherwise any of 0-9 or dash.

```
/^[\d-]*\d[\d-]*$/

%w{555-555-555 12-2314-425 -34--53-343 -------------}.each{|s| puts "#{s} #{s.match(/^[\d-]*\d[\d-]*$/) ? 'does' : 'does not'} match"}

555-555-555 does match
12-2314-425 does match
-34--53-343 does match
------------- does not match
```

If you're trying to recognize phone numbers, you probably want something that recognizes sequences of digits optionally separated by single dashes, try this instead:

```
/^\d+(?:-\d+)*$/
```

Which excludes leading or trailing dashes and doubled dashes.

Comment: +1: Deleted my answer, realized it was the same as this except you used `\d`. Here's [a link](http://rubular.com/r/IX1r3vaH9N) to see your's working.

Comment: Well if they decide not to use dashes that's fine too. I guess a more accurate way to say it is, they can only have numbers or dashes present.

Answer (score 3):

Don't know ruby, but I assume the regex is:

```
/^[0-9]([0-9]|-(?!-))+$/
```

1. Start with a number,
2. Followed by either a number, or a dash not preceded by a dash. Multiple times possible (`555-54-456` is valid, `555--54-456` is not)

Comment: Yep, but I assumed with _'fine for now'_ I assumed the OP meant: _'would be nice to catch to, but not yet strictly necessary at this point'_. As these are telephone numbers, do you see a use for a starting dash, or a repeated dash? I tried to answer with telephone numbers in mind rather then the abstract case.